# При использовании CRITICAL_SECTION многопоточное приложение становится однопоточным

Tags: c++, многопоточность, concurrency, c++11

В параллельных потоках запускается функция:

```
    for(int i=0; i<20; ++i)
        add_vect(2);
```

если использую блокировку с помощью CRITICAL_SECTION:

```
void add_vect(int i) {
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    vInt.push_back(i);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
};
```

то все идет последовательно, результат такой

```
01111111111111111111122222222222222222222443333333333333333333355033333333333333
33333311111111111111111111222222222222222222224455033333333333333333333222222222
22222222222111111111111111111114455033333333333333333333111111111111111111112222
22222222222222224455033333333333333333333222222222222222222221111111111111111111
14455
```

если использую блокировку с помощью мьютекса:

```
void add_vect(int i) {
    lock_guard<mutex> lg(lock_vect);
    vInt.push_back(i);
};
```

то все хорошо, результат такой:

```
01111111111111111111122222222222222222222443333333333333333333355033313213213213
21321321321321321321321321321321321321321212124455032321321321321321321321321321
32132132132132132132132132132114455031312312312312312312312312312312312312312312
31231231231231224455022222222222222222222111313131313131313131313131313131313133
34455
```

чем обусловлено такое поведение?

кому интересно вот исходник:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

mutex global,lock_vect;

condition_variable allow_ex_cond;
int allow_iteration = -1;

condition_variable finished_ex_cond;
int finished_ex = 0;

CRITICAL_SECTION cs;

bool finished_del1 = false;
bool finished_del2 = false;
bool exitTreads = false;

const int num_workers = 3;

vector <int> vInt;

void add_vect(int i) {
    //EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    lock_guard<mutex> lg(lock_vect);
    vInt.push_back(i);
    //LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
};

void gen()
{
    const int maxiterations = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxiterations; i++)
    {
        add_vect(0);
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> l(global);

            // start new iteration
            finished_ex = 0;
            finished_del1 = false;
            finished_del2 = false;
            allow_iteration = i;
            exitTreads = (i == maxiterations - 1);

            allow_ex_cond.notify_all();

                // wait for threads to finish
            finished_ex_cond.wait(l, [] { return finished_ex == num_workers; });
        }
    }
}

void ex1()
{
    int iteration = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        // delete elements from listDelay
        for(int i=0; i<20; ++i)
            add_vect(1);

        {
            unique_lock<mutex> l(global);

            finished_del1 = true;
            allow_ex_cond.notify_all();

            // signal finished
            finished_ex++;
            if (finished_ex == num_workers)
                finished_ex_cond.notify_all();

            // check exit
            if (exitTreads)
                break;

            iteration++;

            // wait for signal to continue
            allow_ex_cond.wait(l, [iteration] { return allow_iteration == iteration; });
        }
    }
}

void ex2()
{
    int iteration = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        // generate new elements to listDelay
        // delete elements from listProc
        for(int i=0; i<20; ++i)
            add_vect(2);

        {
            unique_lock<mutex> l(global);
            allow_ex_cond.wait(l, [] { return finished_del1; }); // why it works??
        }

        // copy elements in listDelay
        for(int i=0; i<2; ++i)
            add_vect(4);

        {
            unique_lock<mutex> l(global);

            finished_del2 = true;
            allow_ex_cond.notify_all();

            // signal finished
            finished_ex++;
            if (finished_ex == num_workers)
                finished_ex_cond.notify_all();

            // check exit
            if (exitTreads)
                break;

            iteration++;

            // wait for signal to continue
            allow_ex_cond.wait(l, [iteration] { return allow_iteration == iteration; });
        }
    }
}

void ex3()
{
    int iteration = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        // generate new elements to listProc
        for(int i=0; i<20; ++i)
            add_vect(3);

        {
            unique_lock<mutex> l(global);
            allow_ex_cond.wait(l, [] { return finished_del2; }); // why it works??
        }

        // copy new elements in listProc
        for(int i=0; i<2; ++i)
            add_vect(5);

        {
            unique_lock<mutex> l(global);

            // signal finished
            finished_ex++;
            if (finished_ex == num_workers)
                finished_ex_cond.notify_all();

            // check exit
            if (exitTreads)
                break;

            iteration++;

            // wait for signal to continue
            allow_ex_cond.wait(l, [iteration] { return allow_iteration == iteration; });
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
    thread tgen;

    {
        unique_lock<mutex> l(global);
        tgen = thread(gen);
        allow_ex_cond.wait(l, [] { return allow_iteration == 0; });
    }

    thread t1(ex1);
    thread t2(ex2);
    thread t3(ex3);

    tgen.join();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);

for (vector <int>::iterator it=vInt.begin(); it != vInt.end(); ++it){
        cout << *it;
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что вы ожидаете от объектов синхронизации?

Comment: я ожидал в обоих случаях результат как при блокировки мьютексом

Comment: Совершенно не ясно как у вас осуществляется вывод и что именно выводится. Есть ли блокировка на вывод?

Comment: вывод осуществляется уже после завершения потоков.

Comment: У вас сколько вообще процессов? CRITICAL_SECTION работает только в пределах одного процесса.

Comment: ну два процесса я создавать не умею, да и не нужно это мне, так что думаю все работает в одном процессе

Comment: Тогда зачем вам мютекс?

Comment: Так и что выводится-то? Вектор? Разделители в выводе были бы полезны... И не ясно чем "хорошая" работа отличается от "плохой".

Comment: есть 3 потока и они пишут данные в один массив. для синхронизации нужно чтото использовать.

Comment: Я думаю что вариант с CritSect работает корректно: одновременная запись в массив из разных потоков исключена. А потоки могут работать с разными скоростями...

Comment: Блокировки не гарантируют порядок поступления данных к ним в очередь, они только предотвращают одновременный доступ к разделяемому ресурсу.

Comment: "хорошая" работа это когда все три потока записывают данные по очереди,  условно "плохая" это когда один поток полностью записывает все свои 20 данных друг за другом

Comment: возможно критическая секция просто на порядок быстрее мьютекса и два других потока просто не успевают включится в работу, когда первый отпускает секцию, прокручивает цикл и вновь захватывает секцию

Comment: Не стоит надеяться на время выполнения функций в этом деле.

Comment: спасибо всем!
я понимаю, что использовать CritSect при использовании классов из с++11 не совсем корректно, но время работы программы при добавлении элементов в массив при использовании мьютекса возрастает в 3 с лишним раза по сравнению с секциями, поэтому остановлю свой выбор на них.

Comment: Читайте теорию, там черным по белому написано что секции это лайт версия мютексов и работают они значительно быстрее.

Comment: @cpp_user в том то и дело, говорят что работают быстрее, но никто не говорит на сколько, у меня получилось на 33млн блокировок/разблокировок, 139с против  37с.

Comment: Это все индивидуально. ;-) Бывает что однопоточная без секций еще быстрее работает чем многопоточная из секциями потому что  очередь очень плотно забита и потоки много времени ждут отбирая ресурсы и тормозят основную обработку. ;-)